# what's the best practice of Spring data JPA query on many optional parameters?

Tags: java, django, jpa

I have a mysql table with many columns, and the users need to query based on arbitrary column (or columns).
In django I can easily test the existence of the query parameters and append the queryset likewise.
But I'm new to JPA, which seems u have to declare all the possible combinations of query parameters in JpaRepository.
or u will have to concatenate the raw sql yourself.

So whats the best practice of JPA on arbitrary combination of query parameters? Thank u.

Comment: Define all the parameters and make them optional

Comment: Yes I have done that, but the actual query code became so long, so i was seeking a better way of writing the query code

Comment: Sadly no, best you can do is format the query nicely so it is easy to read